# on change event for several selects, some with multiple set

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several selects, which all share the same class

```js
$(".my-select").on("change", function() {
  console.log(this)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="my-select">
  <option value="option1">1</option>
  <option value="option2">2</option>
  <option value="option3">3</option>
</select>

<select class="my-select" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="option1">1</option>
  <option value="option2">2</option>
  <option value="option3">3</option>
</select>
```

However, the "on change" only gets fired when multiple is not set on the select.

What is the most efficient way, baring in mind I may have several selects on my page, some showing multiple others not, to get a change event? Vanilla JS or Jquery is fine.

Comment: Are the contents of these selected elements the same?

Comment: That does not seem correct. I made your code runnable with a log and I a seeing it called. What steps are you taking that it is not getting run? Is the problem reading all the selected values the use picked?

Comment: Thanks for the proper formatting, I didnt know I could do that on here. You are correct and clearly, it works, I have no idea why mine doesn't so ill have to just go off and see what's what. i would delete this question if i knew how. I have marked the other guy as the answer, as I couldnt do anything with your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".my-select").change(function() {
    console.log($(this).index(), $(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="my-select">
  <option value="option1">1</option>
  <option value="option2">2</option>
  <option value="option3">3</option>
</select>

<select class="my-select" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="option4">4</option>
  <option value="option5">5</option>
  <option value="option6">6</option>
</select>

<select class="my-select">
  <option value="option7">7</option>
  <option value="option8">8</option>
  <option value="option9">9</option>
</select>

<select class="my-select" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="option10">10</option>
  <option value="option11">11</option>
  <option value="option12">12</option>
</select>
```

This works as expected. Notice that `multiple` values are an Array of selected Values.

Comment: You're correct. I have no idea why mine is not working, but you have given the right answer

Comment: @user2445278 you were using `.on("change")` where I used `.change()`. There are some subtle differences in the two.